# GCMからRegistrationIDが取得できない件について

Tags: android, java, gcm

Android開発者です。
現在開発しているアプリにおいて、
push通知を配信する際、GCMからRegistrationIDが取得できない端末が複数存在します。

内部調査を実施したところ、
google-play-service.jarライブラリに存在する
com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaginクラス内の
registerメソッドにおいて、Exceptionが発生していると推測されます。
google-play-service.jarのバージョンは8.1.15

また、上記原因を特定するため、事象が発生している端末に対してデバックアプリを作成したところ、下記URLソースの64-65行目でExceptionが発生します。

ソース
*https://github.com/google/gcm/blob/399e88c1ef5bb95395b6392f9061e45b2fb5d49a/samples/android/gcm-demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/logic/InstanceIdHelper.java#L55-L98*

当事象が発生する原因について、ご教授いただければと思います。

Answer (score 1):

一部端末でできないようなのでこれかもしれません。

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>`
Android 4.0.4　以前（4.0.4含まない）では上記のパーミッションが必要です。
4.0.4を含むそれ以降は必要ありません。